# Writing a PowerShell Script that alerts when a Team will be archived/is archived

Tags: microsoft-teams

I just discovered the beauty of PowerShell and Teams and I was wondering if it is possible to write a Script, that:

1. Alerts/Sends Mail when a Team will be archived/is archived

I just thought, it would be super awesome if all team members get an email notification (Let's say 14 days in advance) before the team will be archived.
If anybody has something for me, i would appreciate it very much

Cheers,

Mike

Answer (score 2):

You can achive above requirement using Office 365 Security and Compliance
Please Login to [Office 365 Security and Compliance](https://protection.office.com/homepage)
choose alert policies.
click new alert policy --> search Team-->
choose teams create, deletion alerts and choose email address of recipients. Save the policy. It will send notifications. [image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but if i search after "Team" i always get no data available, do you have a clue why that is?

Comment: Please go through below link. https://www.azure365pro.com/notification-on-new-team-creation-using-office365-group-alert/

Comment: Thanks for the Instruction, but do you know it it requires a certain license to accomplish this? Since i can't find it either with your instrucitons

Comment: Please go through this ms docs link. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/audit-log-events.         note:Audit data is only visible in the audit log if auditing is turned on

Comment: please let us know if your issue has been resolved.